# mysql-connector-python ocassionally meets ssl wrong version number error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I use python with flask and mysql as a web server. That issue occurs occasionally and suddenly when mysql connection is running normally, but it worked fine before today. :)

My mysql server is running in a local docker container, and I never use any ssl or secure option.

Environment:
Windows 10, python 3.8.0, mysql-connector-python 8.0.18, official mysql docker image

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 249, in recv_plain
        chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
    File "D:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\ssl.py", line 1226, in recv
        return self.read(buflen)
    File "D:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\ssl.py", line 1101, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2560)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    File "D:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 277, in recv_plain
        raise errors.OperationalError(
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2560)
```

python code:

```py
import mysql.connector

class MysqlConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
            user='root', 
            password='example',
            host='127.0.0.1'
        )
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Comment: Hey, are you able to get this solved? I am having the same problem